# Can't get JSON String by using gson.toJson(Element), {module java.base does not "opens java.util" to module com.google.gson]

Tags: java, json, gson, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am developing a minecraft-forge mod that collecst data from the game and converts the whole data as a JSON string. The mod was working fine while my class had just these fields:

```
public class MyInfo {

    public int ID;
    public float Health;
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public MyInfo(Player play) {
        ID = play.getId();
        Health = play.getHealth();
        X = play.getX();
        Y = play.getY();
        Z = play.getZ();
    }
```

`Player` is an instance of `net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player` where I can retrieve some data I want.

It was working fine and the line where I make the JSON string was not facing any issue.

```
Gson _Json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
MyInfo pers = new MyInfo(player);
String Data = _Json.toJson(pers);
```

***THE ISSUE:***

As soon as I add an `ArrayList` field inside my `MyInfo` class, as I will show now:

```
public class MyInfo {

    public int ID;
    public float Health;
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
    public ArrayList<MobEffectInstance> ActivePotionEffects;

    public MyInfo(Player play) {
        ID = play.getId();
        Health = play.getHealth();
        X = play.getX();
        Y = play.getY();
        Z = play.getZ();
        ActivePotionEffects = new ArrayList<>(play.getActiveEffects()); //the method .getActiveEffects returns a Collection<MobEffectIstance>
    }
```

The thread encounters an exception as soon as it reaches the line where i use `_Json.toJson(pers)`, the exception says:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: 
Unable to make field private final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong java.util.Random.seed accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to module com.google.gson
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:44)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:159)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) 
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) 
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)        
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:727)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:628)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/com.google.gson@2.8.9/com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:607)
```

If I instantiate an `ArrayList<Integer>` in the same class where `_Json` is instantiated and filling it thanks to FOR loop, and then using `toJson()`, the problem about accessing to `java.lang` for `Gson` doesn't appear

i.e:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       numbers.add(i);
}
Gson _Json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
MyInfo playr = new MyInfo(player); 
String Data = _Json.toJson(numbers); //<-- not passing *playr* anymore, but *numbers*
```

***EDIT:***

I found a workaround, it mainly works for my purpose, and is to have the type `MobEffectInstance` decomposed into primitive data types (i.e `String` or `Integer`) and put these values ​​inside a collection

```
public class MyInfo {

    public int ID;
    public float Health;
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
    public HashMap<String,Integer> ActivePotionEffects;

    public MyInfo(Player play) {
        ID = play.getId();
        Health = play.getHealth();
        X = play.getX();
        Y = play.getY();
        Z = play.getZ();
        ActivePotionEffects = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<MobEffectInstance> Temp = new ArrayList<>(play.getActiveEffects());
        for (MobEffectInstance mobEffectInstance : Temp) {
            ActivePotionEffects.put(mobEffectInstance.getDescriptionId(), mobEffectInstance.getDuration());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no experience with [minecraft](https://www.minecraft.net) but your error message indicates a problem with [Java] [modules](https://www.oracle.com/il-en/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) Usually you fix such problems either by modifying the `module-info.java` file or by setting options in the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) command.

Comment: i've tried with `java --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=org.google.gson`, but it's not working, and the problem is that even if i make it work in my IDE with java commands, there are no certainties that Minecraft runs the same commands

Answer (score -2):

Where you initialise your arraylist you have empty <> brackets, they should have MobEffectInstance in them.

Comment: No need, Java has a Dynamic Lookup on parametrized classes, when you declare a specific parameter in a paramatrized Collection, Java will define the similar constructor method to use